# Implement service worker to clean cache of the app on each publish

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I'm currently working on ASP.Net Core App with Angular 8 for the front-end, so I have some problems with the cache thing; each time I publish a new version of my app, the DOM is not making the changes in the case of the front end. So I decided to install a service worker as:

```
ng add @angular/pwa@v8-lts
```

So, this created a few files and changed others:

**Changes:**

- angular.json
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- index.html
- app.module

**Created:**

- manifest.webmanifest
- ngsw-config.json

So I read how to clean the cache and it says to add something like this to service worker:

```
constructor(updates: SwUpdate) {
    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      if (promptUser(event)) {
        updates.activateUpdate().then(() => document.location.reload());
      }
    });
  }
```

But my question is, on what document should I add that? Do I need to create a new file? How I should bind it to my app?

Comment: try to add these lines of code in your `app.component.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need it,
I guess all you need is
hashing the file names every time you build your angular project.
**so with hashed file names the browser can't cache them**.
if it's true ,you can use this command

```
ng build --output-hashing=all
```

> Define the output filename cache-busting hashing mode.

generated files will be like this:

```
main.62beb1fb93041eb44194.js
```

Comment: I already do that but it don't work, that's why I decided to implemented a service worker

Comment: are you sure ? check your project config with someone,it is not reasonable to write a service worker for it,every angular programmer uses this switch command for cache busting.any way it seems you know that what you are doing.:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create service that uses `SwUpdate` to check for updates and force reload if needed, then you can use e.g. `APP_INITIALIZER` to trigger this check on app start.

Comment: Is not the same if I place that on the `app.component.ts`?

Comment: It is not about place, you can put put it to `app.component.ts` and invoke service method from there, the outcome is the same.